# "C++ Templates: The Complete Guide" (c) 2002 -- up to date with C++11?

Tags: c++, templates

The book *C++ Templates: The Complete Guide*, (c) 2002, looks very appealing to me, but as it's 12 years old, I'm concerned it may be out of date.  There are some highly favorable Amazon reviews dated as recently as a year ago, and I don't see any other very recent titles on C++ templates.  Does anyone know whether a book about templates published in 2002 (as opposed to a book specifically about the STL) would have syntax or concepts that have been superseded or added to by, say, C++11?

The following is from [the Amazon book description](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003YL3OYG):

> Templates are among the most powerful features of C++, but they are
>   too often neglected, misunderstood, and misused. C++ Templates: The
>   Complete Guide provides software architects and engineers with a clear
>   understanding of why, when, and how to use templates to build and
>   maintain cleaner, faster, and smarter software more efficiently.
>
> C++ Templates begins with an insightful tutorial on basic concepts and
>   language features. The remainder of the book serves as a comprehensive
>   reference, focusing first on language details, then on a wide range of
>   coding techniques, and finally on advanced applications for templates.
>   Examples used throughout the book illustrate abstract concepts and
>   demonstrate best practices.
>
> Readers learn
>
> - The exact behaviors of templates
> - How to avoid the pitfalls associated with templates
> - Idioms and techniques, from the basic to the previously undocumented
> - How to reuse source code without threatening performance or safety
> - How to increase the efficiency of C++ programs
> - How to produce more flexible and maintainable software

Comment: As the C++ language itself changes only slowly (major changes are made only every 10 years) and remains largely backwards compatible, books on C++ don't age that fast either.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Updated (2016/08/24)

Recommended article with focus on C++11:

[An introduction to C++'s SFINAE concept: compile-time introspection of a class member (Jean Guegant)](https://jguegant.github.io/blogs/tech/sfinae-introduction.html)

---

As a learner of C++ Template Metaprogramming a few months ago, I would still recommend to read this book.

It does not include C++11, but it lays out the syntax and the C++ specifications on how a compiler should process template code. The book covers a lot of less known corners which will become crucial if you need to use C++ templates substantially, whether or not metaprogramming is involved.

---

The missing parts from C++11 are:

- Type Trait Support.

  - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types
  - For navigation, mouse over the "Type Support" near the top of the page. A list of `is_*` will be displayed.
- `decltype`. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype
- `declval`. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval
- `move` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move
- `forward` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward

---

There is a construct which you will see a lot in code that is pasted onto Stackoverflow: `std::enable_if`. However, in practice, I find this quite difficult to use, because of the One-Definition Rule and SFINAE. This is why this book is important, because it goes over the basics.

---

If you use C++ templates substantially in a cross-platform library, you will need to test-compile your code in different compilers. This is because each compiler has different level of compliance to the C++ specification. Code that compiles fine on one may be reject by the other, and occasionally the compiler that accepts it is the one that breaks the specification.

---

Here is my reading notes when I go through this book. Hope it will be helpful.

Book reading notes - C++ Templates - The Complete Guide (2003)

- Ch 2.5 - Function Templates - Summary

  - Overload resolution, and best practices
- Ch 3.3 - Specialization of Class Templates
- Ch 3.4 - Partial Specialization

  - Ambiguity (ODR error), and how to resolve it. ODR = One-Definition Rule
- Ch 4.3 - Restrictions for Non-type Template Parameters

  - Example: string literals with external linkage
- Ch 5 and Ch 6 - These two chapters are very depressing. You may want to skip it and then go back when you are emotionally ready for using templates.
- Part II (Ch 8 - Ch ???) The section of advanced stuff.
- Ch 8 - More rules

  - For a programmer already familiar with the entire Ch 3 (class templates - basics), Ch 8.1 and 8.2 should be read immediately following Ch 3, because the additional rules are just as important and relevant as the basic rules. This will save some pain.
- Ch 8.3.1 (Page 106 in 12th Printing) mentions SFINAE for the first time.
- Ch 8.3 - This section introduces a lot of circumstances where template argument substitution would have led to nonsensical syntactic expansions (and thus become invalid, which in return necessitates SFINAE). This chapter has a steep learning curve even for the experienced C++ programmers.
- Ch 11 - Template Argument Deduction

  - Ch11 contains some contrived Template Argument Deduction examples that are necessary for understanding some of the equally contrived SFINAE applications.
- Ch 12.4 onward - Partial class template specialization.

  - This covers the internal mechanics that is often called upon in an SFINAE application.

Part III (Ch 17 - Ch ???) Metaprogramming.

- Ch 17 - Begins with introductory functional programming.
- App. A.3 - One-Definition Rule (ODR) in detail.

Comment: The problem with a pre-C++11 discussion of TMP is it won't cover `constexpr` and will therefore recommend TMP for all metaprogramming, even cases where `constexpr` functions and types would be far better suited.